# jQuery getting value from dynamic array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with divs ids (in my case its all divs ID values od parent div (#area) ):

```
jQuery.fn.getIdArray = function () {
 var ret = [];
 $('[id]', this).each(function () {
  ret.push(this.id);
 });
 return ret;
 };

var array = $("#area").getIdArray();
```

I need to get an array field value, something like this:

```
var lef = $("#array".[0]).css("left");
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a bit *too* "minimal". ;-) What is `getIdArray`'s return value? What do you mean you need to get an array field value (the phrase is fairly clear, but then the code after it doesn't seem to relate to it).

Comment: This is how you use array $('#'+array[0]).css("left");

Comment: We still don't know what .getIdArray() returns. If you have a custom filter you can: $("#area").filter(function(){//return true if you want this one used}).css("left") to make your custom filter you can:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a wild swing at it (see my comment on the question):

```
var array = $("#area").getIdArray();
var lef=$("#" + array[0]).css("left");
```

That assumes that `getIdArray` returns an array of strings, where each string is an `id` value for a DOM element, and that you want to get the `left` value for the first of those elements.

So for instance, if the array comes back as:

```
["foo", "bar", "charlie"]
```

then the selector created by `"#" + array[0]` is `#foo`, so you end up getting the `left` value for the `foo` element.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an actual JS array within your variable `array` just use bracket notation to access each individual ID.

```
// I have the # before-hand since I'm assuming you have just the ID name
var lef = $('#' + array[0]) // this will access the 1st one in the array
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this :

```
var divYouWantToChange = $("#"+array[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to formulate this as an answer because getIdArray is not a jquery function and we don't know what it does. If you'd like to apply a custom filter to the $("#area") collection you can do so using filter. This will return a jquery object where you can get the .css("left") from.

If you'd like to save both the id's and the left property you can do so with the following code:

```
var objects=[];
$("#area").filter(function(){
  $this=$(this);//cache the object
  objects.push({id:$this.attr("id"),
   left:$this.css("left")
  };
});
console.log(objects);
```